# "Whether they are congruent"

Tags: semantics

A geometry test asks a student to find the length of two pairs of line segments and then instructs the student to

> tell **whether they are congruent** for each pair.

Is the student obligated to tell if a pair is **not** congruent, or only if the pair **is** congruent?

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have your escape clause if the teacher asked you to tell *if* they are congruent. For example, "Can you tell me if that timer goes off?".

But *whether* implies (at least) two alternatives, both of which you're obligated to tell.

Comment: I think that's because *whether* implies *whether or not*, which people often say. You don't really hear *if or not* (although for both words, the *or not* can be tacked on after the proposition being queried).

Comment: ODO Usage note: If and whether are more or less interchangeable in sentences like I’ll see if he left an address; and I’ll see whether he left an address, although whether is generally regarded as more formal and suitable for written use.

Comment: We had a recent question on the "if...or if/whether...or whether" constructions, @z7sgѪ, and I agree they are more or less equivalent. But is there not an additional sense of "if" when used without a list, where it means "if and when"? While substituting "whether" would be translated "whether or not"...That is what I was referring to in my example about the timer going off.

Comment: Yes there is an additional sense of *if* in your example, meaning "in the event that" and *whether* never has this sense.  Substituting whether would be less ambiguous.  However, I think in this case, the obtuse schoolboy (or -girl) should just answer the damn question!

Comment: I think it's @EdR himself trying to get out of answering the question, which is why I am cutting him no slack here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Often `whether` can expanded to imply `whether this... or not` thereby demanding an answer irrespective of it being in affirmative or negative.